# How to send form with ajax post request with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activeadmin

I want to send whole form inputs using ajax with a post request.
I'm using this code of js :

```
$.post('#{my_custom_action_path}', $('#myform').serialize(), function(data) {
    console.log("Success !")
});
```

The problem is that the form is generated by rails with a "_method" input containing "patch"
This result of using the wrong route (it use a patch route, not the post one i've defined in my routes)

How to change the _method field before sending the form via ajax ?

Comment: Can you show generated html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the input value by javascript as well before sending:

```
$("input[name='_method']").val('post');
```

OR you can skip this field when serialize the form:

```
$('#myform').find("input[name!='_method']").serialize()
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a solution. I've used this derivate solution : `form_data = $('#myform').serialize().replace('&_method=patch&', '&');`

Comment: Solution suggested in this answer is generally a good idea, but might get you in trouble if you use elements of type other than `input` in your form. Please check my answer below for more generic approach.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is specifying `method: post` on the Rails form generator like so:

`<%= simple_form_for @model, html: {method: :post} do |form| %>`

or just `method: post` if you're using `form_for @model`.

How this works:

If you look at the HTML Rails generates, you'll see that `<form>` tag already has `method="post"`, but as you said Rails generates a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">` which, when serialized by Jquery and sent via AJAX, will make Rails look for a `patch` route instead of a `post` route, regardless of what you set in `type` or `method` inside your `$.axax({})` settings.

When you define `method: post` in your template, Rails will keep the `<form>` with `method="post"`, BUT it will avoid generating that hidden field tag which fools the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jQuery ajax `$.post` shorthand method, which is short for:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

If you use this longer form, it is easy to replace `POST` with `PATCH`.

Comment: I don't want to use patch, but post. The problem is that the form generated by rails contain a "_method" input that has for value "patch". This is used be rails to override the HTTP verb by the one specified in the input. This is the normal behavior of the form. But i want, for some reasons, send this post via ajax with post

Comment: Ah, excuse me. Well, what if you use the longer form with `POST`?

Comment: Same behavior with longer form.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('form').find("[name!='_method']").serialize()`

This
will find all elements of the form that are not named `_method`.

This is not to be confused with `$('#myform').find("input[name!='_method']").serialize()` (as in answer suggested before).
This line will find all **input (and only input)** elements that are not named `_method`. If you have other elements in your form, such as *select* or *textarea* this line will essentially strip them away too.